# enviar funcion js por ruta

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs

Quiero ejecutar una funcion de un archivo js a traves de una ruta, sin embargo no logro pillar los parametros bien, dandome un fallo en el parametro num, lo que quiero conseguir es que cuando coloque en mi navegador por ejemplo http://127.0.0.3:8083/dni?num=12345678, gracias a la función, pues me de el resultado de la letra final de ese dni que he escrito, pero me falla el programa no detectando el parametro sum, adjunto mi codigo js junto a la función que estoy usando.

```js
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');
var ltr = require('./letra.js');


http.createServer(function (peticion, respuesta) {
    var ruta = url.parse(peticion.url, true);
    var pathname = ruta.pathname;
    var nombreFichero = "./instrucciones.html";
    console.log(pathname);
    //ruta default
    if (pathname == '/') {
        respuesta.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'text/html;charset=utf-8'
        });
        respuesta.write('<p>¡Saludos!, sea bienvenido a mi página web.</p>');
        respuesta.end();
        

    }
    //ruta dni | Mostrar html instrucciones
    else if (pathname == '/dni') {
        fs.readFile(nombreFichero, function (err, dato) {
            if (err) {
                respuesta.writeHead(404, {
                    'Content-Type': 'text/html'
                });
                return respuesta.end('<p>ERROR 404: Página no encontrada</p>');
            }
            //Definir letra de DNI
            if (ruta.query.num !== undefined) {
                respuesta.write("Tu DNI es " + ruta.query.num + '' + ltr.letraDNI())
            }
            respuesta.writeHead(200, {
                'Content-Type': 'text/html;charset=utf-8 '
            });
            respuesta.write(dato);
            respuesta.end();
        });
        //respuesta.write('<p>COMPROBACIÓN: La ruta /dni, funciona correctamente.</p>');
    } 
    //ruta escribir
    else if (pathname == '/escribir') {
        respuesta.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'text/html;charset=utf-8'
        });
        respuesta.write('<p>COMPROBACIÓN: La ruta /escribir, funciona correctamente.</p>');
        respuesta.end();
    }
    //sino es ruta dni ni ruta escribir
    else if (pathname != '/dni' || pathname != '/escribir') {
        respuesta.writeHead(200, {

            'Content-Type': 'text/html;charset=utf-8'
        });
        respuesta.write('AVISO: Te has adentrado en territorio equivocado, forastero.');
        respuesta.end();
    }
    //Error 404
    else {
        respuesta.writeHead(404, {
            'Content-Type': 'text/html;charset=utf-8'
        });
        respuesta.write('<p>ERROR 404: Página no encontrada</p>');

    }

}).listen(8083, '127.0.0.3');
console.log('Servidor ejecutándose en http://127.0.0.3:8083/');
console.log('Bienvenido usuario...');
```

```js
exports.letraDNI=function(num)
{
    let letra="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOQRSTUWXYZ"
    return letra.charAt('Tu letra final del DNI es ' + num%24);

}
```

Comment: Diria que tal como estan puestos los `else if` solo te pilla el primero que coincide con la url (`else if (pathname == '/dni') {`) y por eso no llega al segundo (`else if (ruta.parametros.num !== undefined) {`).  Mira de poner el segundo como un if normal dentro del primero.

Comment: Lo he cambiado de sitio, pero tampoco funciona.

Comment: Es que ahora que lo veo, eso es nodejs, del cual no tengo ni idea, pero lo que no me parece lógico es que uses `parametros` como si eso lo hubieras definido antes, pues no lo veo tampoco.  Segun leo por ahi, deberias usar `ruta.query.num` para conseguir ese dato en lugar de `parametros` que no veo de donde lo sacas

Comment: Tienes razón, lo he corregido, ahora no me da fallos, pero me saca una pagina en blanco, seguiré buscando a ver de que se trata el error.

Comment: Quizás tienes que bajar un poco mas el `if (ruta.query.num !== undefined) {`... ponlo justo antes o despues de `respuesta.write(dato);`  para que primero escriba la cabecera esa del `writeHead`

Comment: Efectivamente eso era lo que me faltaba, ¡muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda, me has ayudado mucho :)!

Comment: jeje, me alegro! :-)  No se si vale la pena redactar una respuesta o lo dejo asi

Comment: Entiendo que el DNI no es Español, porque en ese caso la lista de letras es incorrecta.

Comment: Sisi, también he arreglado eso jajaja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenia varios fallos que hemos ido arreglando en los comentarios, a saber:

1. Tenia mal puestos los `if` - `elseif` [en un principio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/f7408993-c46c-4fca-b6a3-4f4894e03c0f/view-source) y no conseguia llegar a evaluar el parámetro pasado porque se detenia en otro antes.
2. Luego tenia mal puesta la sintaxis para recuperar el parámetro de la query pasada, pues usaba `ruta.parametros.num` en lugar de `ruta.query.num`, que es la sintaxis correcta para recuperar parámetros de una query cuando antes se habia parseado con `var ruta = url.parse(peticion.url, true);`.
3. Y finalmente, aunque en el punto 1 habia arreglado lo del `if` - `elseif`, aún no lo habia puesto en el orden correcto, pues estaba por encima del writeHead así:

```javascript
//Definir letra de DNI
            if (ruta.query.num !== undefined) {
                respuesta.write("Tu DNI es " + ruta.query.num + '' + ltr.letraDNI())
            }
            respuesta.writeHead(200, {
                'Content-Type': 'text/html;charset=utf-8 '
            });
            respuesta.write(dato);
            respuesta.end();
```

Cuando tenia que ser así:

```javascript
//Definir letra de DNI
            respuesta.writeHead(200, {
                'Content-Type': 'text/html;charset=utf-8 '
            });
            if (ruta.query.num !== undefined) {
                respuesta.write("Tu DNI es " + ruta.query.num + '' + ltr.letraDNI())
            }
            respuesta.write(dato);
            respuesta.end();
```

Es decir, primero escribir la cabecera y luego el resto.